# issue when variable substitution using set command in jinja2 template

Tags: yaml, jinja2

I have a YAML file that has default value for two dict defined as follows:

```
sample:
  high:
    name: high-volume
    alias: hi-vl

hi-vl:
  ab1:    
    add:
      range: 0
      range1: 0
    remove:
      range: -1
      range1: -1
```

To iterate and get the values from jinja2 template i am using the code below:

```
{% for key, value in sample.iteritems() %}
{% set al = value.alias %}
{% for key1, value1 in al.iteritems()  %}
```

When I execute this template to generate the YAML file I get the error:

```
"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'iteritems'"}
```

The set variable is changing the variable as unicode.
If I substitute the direct `value` instead of `value.alias` in the set statement the iteration works fine.

I tried using filters like `to_yaml`, `tojson` but they convert to string and not render as dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python to convert the yaml to dict, create the jinja string, load the jinja string into a `Template` class and render it:

Consider the yaml is stored in a file called `specs.yaml`. We will first open it and convert it to a dict:

```
import yaml
import json
from jinja2 import Template

with open('specs.yaml') as f:
  specs = f.read()
  specs_dict = yaml.load(specs) #get dict from yaml

print(json.dumps(test, indent=4)) #print pretty dict tree
#Output:

{
"sample": {
    "high": {
        "name": "high-volume",
        "alias": "hi-vl"
    }
},
"hi-vl": {
    "ab1": {
        "add": {
            "range": 0,
            "range1": 0
        },
        "remove": {
            "range": -1,
            "range1": -1
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now, we can define the jinja string and create a template object to render it.

```
#form jinja string
jinja_string = """{% for key, value in specs_dict['sample'].items() %}                              
{% set al = value['alias'] %}
{% for key, value in specs_dict[al].items() %}
{{key}}:{{value}}
{% endfor %}                        
{% endfor %}"""

# create template object and render it
template = Template(jinja_string)
print(template.render(specs_dict=specs_dict))
#Output:
ab1:{'add': {'range': 0, 'range1': 0}, 'remove': {'range': -1, 'range1':-1}}
```